# event machine with em http gem cannot load middleware oauth

Tags: ruby, oauth, middleware, eventmachine, em-http-request

I am trying to get the stock price streaming to work using TradeKing API

https://developers.tradeking.com/documentation/ruby-streaming

or the copied and pasted codes below

```
require 'em-http'
require 'em-http/middleware/oauth'

credentials = {
  :consumer_key        => "<CONSUMER_KEY>",
  :consumer_secret     => "<CONSUMER_SECRET>",
  :access_token        => "<ACCESS_TOKEN>",
  :access_token_secret => "<ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET>"
}

EM.run do
  conn = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('https://stream.tradeking.com/v1/market/quotes.json?symbols=F')
  conn.use EventMachine::Middleware::OAuth, credentials

  http = conn.get
  http.stream { |chunk| puts chunk }

  http.errback do
    EM.stop
  end

  trap("INT")  { http.close; EM.stop }
  trap("TERM") { http.close; EM.stop }
end
```

After getting key, secret, and token, I built a simple Ruby app to play with the codes but I get an error that says it cannot load

`require 'em-http/middleware/oauth'`

If I disable this, the code `EventMachine::Middleware::OAuth` will not work.

Here is the error message:

```
    c:/tools/ruby215/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/
kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file --
simple_oauth (LoadError)
        from c:/tools/ruby215/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubyg
ems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from c:/tools/ruby215/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/em-ht
tp-request-1.1.2/lib/em-http/middleware/oauth.rb:1:in `<top
(required)>'
        from c:/tools/ruby215/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubyg
ems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from c:/tools/ruby215/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubyg
ems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from app.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

I am new to event machine and em-http gem. I looked at their documentation but couldn't find information about this error. Can someone help me figure out why the file cannot load?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I solved this myself. I haven't worked with vanilla Ruby in a while so I got a bit rusty with reading the error messages. The error says that it cannot load the file and points to line 1 of the the `oauth.rb` file which is in the `em-http-request` gem. I looked into the file and the first line says `require simple_oauth` which I haven't installed it yet. I would think installing `em-http-request` gem would install `simple_oauth` as a dependency, but I guess not (well the em-http-request hasn't been updated for several years).

The fix to this problem is to install `simple_oauth` gem.

`gem install simple_oauth`

and run those codes again and it should work.

https://rubygems.org/gems/simple_oauth/versions/0.3.1

https://github.com/laserlemon/simple_oauth

I hope this helps anyone who is having the same problem (since TradeKing API doc isn't as clear).